# Get exit code from a Makefile command and use it as a variable in Git hook

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, githooks, exit-code, php-cs-fixer

I am currently hooking into Git's `pre-push` hook to run PHP CS Fixer, but I'm looking for a more less clunky way of doing it. I couldn't figure out how to pass the GNU Make command's script exit code and pass in to the Git hook script.

File setup

`pre-push`:

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$(make run-cs-fixer)
exitCode="${output##*$'\n'}" # Gets last line printed from cs-fixer.sh
# Use exitCode to continue or halt push
# Exit code from cs-fixer.sh cannot be obtained here. Make seems to produce its own exit code.
```

`Makefile`:

```
run-cs-fixer:
    @-cd docker-compose exec -T workspace bash ./cs-fixer.sh
    # echo $? gives me the exit code from cs-fixer.sh, but it's not available outside of this area, even if exited with it.
```

`cs-fixer.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
./vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix...
exitCode=$?
echo $exitCode # This is the exit code I need
```

So, it goes: `git push...` > `pre-push` > `Makefile` > `cs-fixer` produces exit code  that needs to be available in `pre-push`.

As you can see, I'm printing the exit code manually from `cs-fixer.sh`, so that it can be extracted when the entire output of this script is captured in `pre-push` using `output=$(make run-cs-fixer)`. I just couldn't figure out how to naturally pass the exist code around.

It seems like Make starts a new shell to run its command, so that seems to be one of the problems, but couldn't get `.ONESHELL` to work. I was able to confirm I can echo the desired exit code with the Make command instructions (below `run-cs-fixer:`), but that was still unavailable in `pre-push`.

Comment: Are you sure your `pre-push` script is running in bash?  You are using bash-specific features that won't work in a POSIX shell.  I think you should add an `echo "$output"` after you run make and see what its value is.  I see no reason, from the code here, why it shouldn't contain the exit code.

Comment: the exit code in bash will be available as `$?` directly after the make command

Comment: @MadScientist yeah, it's bash (updated post). `echo "$output"` is giving me the whole CLI output and not the exit code.

Comment: @AnthonySottile I tired that, and the desired code is available there, but not once make command is finished executing, even if I `exit` with that code. Updated post.

Comment: I can't explain how you can see the output from the `./vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer` script but not see the output from the `echo $exitCode` command, unless the `...` in your example in the question somehow hides a way that this script can exit early.  There must be something about this environment that you are not telling us about.

Answer (score 0):

GNU `make` returns the status of its work, per the man page.  You cannot change the exit status of `make` (other than by forcing a 0, 1 or 2 as per the man page).
To do what you want, you will need to capture the output of the make command, say via `echo 0` or `echo $$?` and use that output as the value you're looking for.